error: AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #6: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit
Im trying to create the release app of my flutter project, but when i run
flutter build apk --release

it allways shows this error:
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #6: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #5: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #4: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #0: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #3: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #1: Idle daemon unexpectedly exit. This should not happen.
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #2 Failed to shutdown within timeout
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #2: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:249)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:171)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:206)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:190)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:109)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$leasingAapt2Daemon$1.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:195)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.compile(PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.kt:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnableKt.runAapt2Compile(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:57)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileRunnable.kt:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: O pipe est� sendo fechado
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at 
        ... 44 more
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:249)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:171)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasableAaptDaemon.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:66)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.maintain(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:89)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.Aapt2DaemonManagerMaintainer$firstDaemonStarted$1.run(Aapt2DaemonBuildService.kt:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: O pipe est� sendo fechado
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:160)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:248)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:257)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:239)
        ... 10 more
AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #1 Failed to shutdown within timeout
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-8.7.2-12006047-windows Daemon #1: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:249)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:171)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasableAaptDaemon.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:66)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.maintain(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:89)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: O pipe est� sendo fechado
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:160)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:248)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:257)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:239)
        ... 10 more


I just dont know what to do, i saw other solutions, but all of them are form too old versions and flutter have been changing a lot.
Ive updated de kotlin version, updated the gradle plugins and refresh all android dependecies

This question is similar to: A timeout exception thrown by AAPT2 during the packaging of React Native application on Android. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've noticed that my answer didn't directly address your problem. So I decided to delete it in the meantime. I want to prevent confusion for you and for the others.
